# Problem with a RewriteRule - parameter missing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried back and forth, but I do not get it to work.

This doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^reset-password/token/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/invalid reset-password.php?token=$1&invalid
```

The "invalid" parameter is not included in $_GET, only the "token" parameter.

But without RewriteRule it works:

```
reset-password.php?token=XXXXXXXXXXX&invalid
```

Then both "token" and "invalid" parameter is included in $_GET.

How do I solve it?

Comment: You probably want to try something like that: `...reset-password.php?token=$1&invalid=true` or similar ...

Comment: Or maybe the incoming request is _not_ what you expect, so _not_ something like `reset-password/token/xyz/invalid` ?

Comment: What you've posted should "work", providing the requested URL is as expected. What URL are you requesting? Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Note that you are missing the `L` flag, so processing is going to continue through the file and may be getting rewritten by other directives? But as noted by arkascha, you should ideally provide a _value_ for the parameter, otherwise `$_GET['invalid']` evaluates to (bool)false, since it is "empty" (so, logically, it could be interpreted as _not invalid_).

Comment: Solved! I moved up this one and added [L]

RewriteRule ^reset-password/token/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/invalid reset-password.php?token=$1&invalid [L]

Comment: So, it would seem you did have a conflict with other directives? Please add your solution as an answer (and later accept it) - to help other readers and remove the question from the unanswered question queue.